# Postgresql: date format and local language output

Tags: postgresql

I have two problem with postgresql.
The first one is I have to convert date in specific format like: friday 04 november 2016

```
SELECT to_char(tstamp, 'Day DD month YYYY') FROM ...
```

that's the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjNnm.png

at first look the tstamp table disappeared and there're more space in the string:

```
friday....04.November..2016
```

*Hex encoding

the second one is that i have to convert it in a language format, in italian for example: "Venerdì 04 Novembre 2016".

Thank's for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About first question: additional spaces are because `month` and `Day` patterns are:

> blank-padded to 9 chars

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html

So, if you want to remove this spaces, you can try something like this:

```
 select trim(to_char(localtimestamp(0), 'Day'))||to_char(localtimestamp(0), ' DD ')||trim(to_char(localtimestamp(0), 'month'))||to_char(localtimestamp(0), ' YYYY')
```

--

About italian language, may be there is another ways too, but this should also work. You can hard coded italian month and day names and "translate" they using `case` expression, something like this:

```
select 
    case 
        when trim(to_char(tstamp, 'Day')) = 'Monday' then 'Monday_in_italian' 
        when trim(to_char(tstamp, 'Day')) = 'Tuesday' then 'Tuesday_in_italian'
        when trim(to_char(tstamp, 'Day')) = 'Wednesday' then 'Wednesday_in_italian' 
        -- another days here
    end||
    to_char(tstamp, ' DD ')||
    case 
        when trim(to_char(tstamp, 'month')) = 'january' then 'January_in_italian'
        when trim(to_char(tstamp, 'month')) = 'february' then 'February_in_italian'
        -- another months here
    end||
    to_char(tstamp, ' YYYY')
    as tstamp 
    from your_table
```

Note, that you should put all 7 day and all  12 month names in case expressions, if you want work this correctly for anytime.

Or even better, in `case` statements, you can use `D` pattern for determine day and `MM` pattern for month. If you want see available patterns list, you can follow link, I've posted above.

Comment: ok thanks but i don't need localtimestamp cause tstamp is a name of a table that contain the timestamp: http://imgur.com/a/PnvYY . that's is original query SELECT tstamp from table and select trim(to_char(tstamp, 'Day')) doesn't work: http://imgur.com/a/eS48T

Comment: What is `tstamp` column type?

Comment: tstamp is the name of column, I've tried your code and that's the result: http://imgur.com/a/8M2nj

Comment: timestamp(6) NOT NULL

Comment: Well, is this what you want? (result on image)

Comment: yes that's it but why "?column"  and not "tstamp" like the original name?

Comment: add at  the end `as tstamp`

Comment: like this: `select trim(to_char(tstamp, 'Day'))||to_char(tstamp, ' DD ')||trim(to_char(tstamp, 'month'))||to_char(tstamp, ' YYYY') as tstamp from your_table`

Comment: it works thanks in part cause i wish to see the output in italian and it end

Comment: yes, is there a way to convert the output in italian? Something like: Venerdì 04 Novembre 2016?

Comment: Yes, there is one way, just a moment

Comment: @Alessandro95 - added one solution for italian language

Answer (score 5):

Oto's answer is all good, but with excessive coding. If your OS does not support Italian localization (`locale -a`), go with it. But if it does, you can format your time like here:

```
t=# set lc_time to 'it_IT.utf8';
SET
Time: 0.295 ms
t=# select to_char(now(), 'TMDay, DD TMMonth YYYY');
         to_char
-------------------------
 Giovedì, 11 Maggio 2017
(1 row)

Time: 3.705 ms
```

Formats anf `TM` prefix explanation [can be found in docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: is there a way to use this in a SELECT, instead of psql?

Comment: sure. the sql above is not psql specific

Comment: Exellent! `TMMonth` and `TMDay` for date format return indeed trimmed full month/day name. Thanks a mil @VaoTsun!